# error in relative path and absolute path in import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following folder structure

```
Tool -> Tool folder have following three subfolders
    inputfiles
    outputfiles
    soucefiles

sourcefiles have following files
       __init__.py
       main.py
       ParseLogFile.py
```

Following are contents of ParseLogFile.py

```
    class ParseLogFile:
        # initialize file name
        def __init__(self, filename):
            self.filename = filename
            return


def ParseLogFileFunc(self):
    print("ParseLogFileFunc called " + self.filename

)
```

Following are contents of main.py

```
from sourcefiles.ParseLogFile import ParseLogFile

parseFile = ParseLogFile("logfile")
parseFile.ParseLogFileFunc()
```

If i use following then it is working

```
    from ParseLogFile import ParseLogFile

parseFile = ParseLogFile("logfile")
parseFile.ParseLogFileFunc()
```

but I am trying to understand absolute and relative paths for import

> Question 1:

**When i gave absolute path like above i am getting followoing error**

```
 from sourcefiles.ParseLogFile import ParseLogFile
```

If i run above file i.e., main.py i am getting following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sourcefiles'
```

How do we rectify this error using abolute path?

**Question 2:If i use relative path**

```
from .ParseLogFile import ParseLogFile

parseFile = ParseLogFile("logfile")
parseFile.ParseLogFileFunc()
```

If i run above file i.e., main.py i am getting following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.ParseLogFile'; '__main__' is not a package
```

**Question 3:
How do open a file by providing relate path in python for example in my case input file in "inputfiles" folder.**

I am new to python and trying to learn python in realistic way used in real projects. Kindly help. I am using python 3.x and spyder tool of anaconda for development

Comment: [How to do relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python/73149)

Answer (score 0):

Q1 & Q2 can be answered by one explanation.
- you        "main.py" and "ParseLogFile.py" are in same that's why just direct from import works as you might already know but when you gave relative path from you side it might be correct but python takes in another way around so in case of relative or absolute path always give using os lib in python. Hardcoding the path create problems most of the time.

Q3
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**))

or you can get the absolute path in the same way.

Comment: @ Junaid Ghauri. Thanks for response. Can you please elaborate what does you mean by python takes in another way around?